# Can I use the Apple Logo in a low run ad (think bulletinboards, not magazines + billboard)?

Tags: logo, copyright, legal

I'm wondering if it would be possible to use the Apple Logo in a really cheap, low-run, homemade A4 ad for Apple-assistance services, without running into issues with Apple themselves?

I'm talking it would be at 300pt in a home-printed A4, not a magazine or a billboard.

I would suppose it would get a run of 20 or 30 printouts. In Finland.

Comment: If you think https://www.apple.com/legal/intellectual-property/guidelinesfor3rdparties.html doesn't apply to your usage for some reason, you should mention why in your question. Also, this is a legal issue, not graphic design.

Comment: Think twice if you are competing with an official Apple service provider in you area.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a legal question

Answer (score 1):

I think -- no lawyer here -- a case could be made for fair use -- if you are absolutely clear that you are offering a service for Apple customers, say, and not that you are offering any Apple-owned product or service, or have the right to use their logo.

Example disclaimers:
All trademarks shown here are the property of their owners. This service is provided by a third party and is not sponsored, endorsed by, or connected with Apple Computer Inc. in any way.

Comment: Yeah, I'm only really tutoring them and assisting them in migrating from PC to Mac.. If they have any software issues with iCloud or Photos or any other Apple apps, I'll help them to the best of my ability. It's a bit more 1-on-1 and for the long haul than just going to a regular Apple Service Provider, and there's no Apple Stores with Apple Geniuses around here. + it's to their home.

Answer (score 0):

To stay on the legal side: Read Apple's rules on what they allow as told in comments. Do not think that "this is so small thing that Apple doesn't care". They will care if they notice and you will pay maybe $15000,- for their costs to cover the caused damage that can be judged to be only $ 100,- or so. Of course, it can be that Apple consider your effort to be useful for Apple's goals. Then, maybe, no consequences. But to be sure, send your work to Apple or its local representative to get a written and signed acceptance before a cry.

The following is ok without a written acceptance:

- A line in the program sheet of Säynämäki Village Summer Festival that states the time and place for "The meeting of senior age friends of iPod" Apple logo there not much bigger than one character.

The following may do need some thinking and refining:

- 10 worst global enterprises that kill children